# Como fazer URL amigável com .htaccess com Variável na URL

Tags: htaccess

**Exemplo tenho link assim:**

https://meusite.com/linkdireto/?id=999

**Tem como acessar assim:**

https://meusite.com/linkdireto/999

Assim ficar com a URL mas limpa, sei que tem como fazer, mas não tenho ideia!

**Meu .htaccess atual:**

```html
# override max php upload settings. Might not work on all servers
#php_value upload_max_filesize 4000M
#php_value post_max_size 4000M

# setup xsendfile if the module is enabled
<IfModule mod_xsendfile.c>
  <Files *.php>
    XSendFile On
    SetEnv MOD_X_SENDFILE_ENABLED 1
  </Files>
</IfModule>

# disable mod security
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    SecFilterEngine Off
#    SecFilterScanPOST Off
#</IfModule>

# redirect www to non-www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On

# Redirecionar para HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#RewriteRule . - [E=no-gzip:1]
RewriteBase /

# forward to install if it exists
#RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/install -d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(install) [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*) /install/ [L,redirect=302]

# forward app requests
#RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
#RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteRule ^app/(.*) plugins/webdav/site/control/$1 [QSA,L]

# forward api requests
RewriteRule ^api/v2/(.*)$ api/v2/index.php?_page_url=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

# route everything via index.php if it doesn't exist as a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_page_url=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No teu htaccess basta fazer o seguinte:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^linkdireto/([0-9]+)?$ meuScript.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

`[0-9]` no caso se seu id for só com números

Comment: E se tiver letras e números ? os dois..

Comment: você poderia fazer `[a-zA-Z0-9]` assim reconhecerá números e letras maiúsculas ou minusculas

Comment: testei e deu erro 404

Comment: Modifiquei minha pergunta meu código atual, pra ver se ajuda..

Comment: Te convém colocar todas as Rewrite rules dentro do IfModule, como não sei qual é a estrutura dos seus arquivos é difícil ajudar, se deu erro 404 então você apontou pro arquivo errado.